# Subquery in cross object

Tags: soql

I've got 3 objects =>
-Object A has a lookup with Object B (Order)
-Obect C (case) has a lookup with Object B

I need to retreive a field on Object C to display with all the field from the Object A (with SOQL) in Visualforcepage.
Any ideas ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You'd use two subqueries:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT Id FROM A__r),
  (SELECT Id FROM C__r)
FROM B__c
WHERE Id IN (SELECT B__c FROM A__c WHERE Id = :aRecordId)
```

If you're using pure Visualforce without Apex, you need to have B's ID, instead:

```
<apex:page standardController="B__c">
  <apex:repeat value="{!B__c.A__r}" var="a">
    {!a.Name}
  </apex:repeat>
  <apex:repeat value="{!B__c.C__r}" var="c">
    {!c.Subject}
  </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```